# Formula exceeding the two column format

Tags: formatting

I use the [amcs](https://www.amcs.uz.zgora.pl/downloads/Instructions_AMCS.pdf):

```
\documentclass{amcs}
\begin{document}
\[ \frac {SySM_Accuracy - Ens_Accuracy}  \sqrt{ \frac {SySM_Accuracy * (1-SySM_Accuracy) } {number of testing rec } + \frac {Ens_Accuracy * (1-Ens_Accuracy) } {number of testing rec } } }\]
\end{document}
```

Following is the result that exceeds the paragraph column. How can I match it to the template?

[image: following result]

Comment: please `\mathrm{SySM}_{\mathrm{Accuracy}}` ! Seeing `Accuracy` typeset as math italic is more painful on the eye than overprinting the next column... (especially if _only_ the A is subscripted)

Comment: Thanks David. Can you please elaborate, I couldn't understand what to do.

Comment: Unrelated to the overprinting (except it will make the formula narrower) use `\mathrm{SySM}_{\mathrm{Accuracy}}` not `SySM_Accuracy ` look at the image you have posted with the A being a subscript and `ccuracy` being set not subscripted and spaced out so that it looks like a product of variables, not a word) (similarly the denominator is unreadable and should be `\text{number of testing rec}` so that it uses a proper font and has word spaces

Comment: it is hard to suggest how to make the formula narrower without subject knowledge. In particular do you  _have_ to subscript your terms with `Accuracy` If you used something else eg `Acc` the expression would probably fit.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please help me to rephrase the formula? I changed it and I have errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no hope of fitting that beast in a narrow column. Use a symbol for the secondary fractions.

```
\documentclass{amcs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\tvar}[2]{%
  \mathrm{#1}_{\mathrm{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author[ad1][]{First name LAST NAME}

\correspondingauthor{Fifth AUTHOR}

\address[ad1]{Institute of xxx xxx xxx xxx\\ University of xxx xxx, 
  Address xxx xxx xx xxx xxx\\ e-mail: \url{xxx xx xxx}}

\maketitle

\lipsum*[1-3]
\[ 
\frac
  {\tvar{SySM}{Accuracy} - \tvar{Ens}{Accuracy}}
  {\sqrt{F(\tvar{SySM}{Accuracy})+F(\tvar{Ens}{Accuracy})}}
\]
where
\[
F(x)=\frac{x(1-x)}{\textup{number of testing rec}}
\]
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

By help of `mathools` package you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\frac{\mathrm{SySM}_{\mathrm{Accuracy}} - \mathrm{Ens}_{\mathrm{Accuracy}}} 
{\sqrt{\splitdfrac{\frac{\mathrm{SySM}_{\mathrm{Accuracy}} * (1-\mathrm{SySM}_{\mathrm{Accuracy}})} 
         {\text{number of testing rec}} + }
                  {\frac{\mathrm{Ens}_{\mathrm{Accuracy}}* (1-\mathrm{Ens}_{\mathrm{Accuracy}})} 
    {\text{number of testing rec}} }
    }
}
\]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

However, more nice result you will obtain if you will obey David Carlisle instructions in his comments above.